# How to run appium test using aluedeke/appium-android docker image?

Tags: java, android, docker, automation, appium

`aluedeke/appium-android` is a Docker image of an Appium REST http interface listener built by aluedeke. This is the repo: https://github.com/aluedeke.
Given that I have never used appium, I have a java file, specifically a test for WhatsApp found [here](https://gist.github.com/sjmach/b1b530a693de647773a2) made by sjmach, I have a running container of aluedeke/appium-android, and I have an Android device plugged in, How do I run that test file on that container(I'm using Ubuntu)?.

Comment: Why don't you simply start off with a basic Appium tutorial itself. Its easier to get and less complicated.

Comment: No it is not less complicated. That would be one way, but it would defeat the purpose of already having a server which supposedly is capable of running a test for me with one terminal command. I already have experience with the underlying technology, selenium that is. Mine is a setup problem, and the set up instructions on the docs are getting me into a lot of trouble. I get rid of those set up issues by using someone else's set up, namely a docker image.